# Handling events raised from a lower level object

Tags: c++, events, gtk

I'm writing a C++ programm using GTK+3.0. Anyway, I think this question may apply to any framework that uses events / signals.

I have a container class, say `containerClass` and a child class, say `childClass`. A `childClass` object `child` is contained inside a `containerClass` object `container`.

The `child` object is written to modify properties of something. To this aim, it has `GtkEntry`, `GtkButton` and so on. When I click the "save button", an event is raised.

This event must be handled by the `container` object, because the `container` is interfaced with a database in someway.

Hereafter, you find the solution I'm using to do the job:

```
// Child class
class childClass {

    void setClickHandler_External(void (*extFun)(string property), void *);
    void (*clickHandler_External)(string, void *);  
    void *clickHandler_External_Data;   

    static void buttonClicked(GtkWidget *widget, void *data);
}

void childClass::setClickHandler_External(void (*extFun)(string), void *data) {

    // Set the external event handler
    clickHandler_External = extFun;
    clickHandler_External_Data = data;
}

void childClass::buttonClicked(GtkWidget *widget, void *data) {
    childClass *m = (childClass *)data;

    // Call the external event handler
    m->clickHandler_External(property, m->clickHandler_External_Data);
}

// Container Class
class containerClass {
    childClass child;
    static void clickHandler(string property, void *data);
}

containerClass::containerClass() {
    // Set the event handler
    child.setClickHandler_External((void(*)(string))&(this->clickHandler), (void *)this);
}


void containerClass::clickHandler(string property, void *data) {
    // Event handler in the upper class

    containerClass *m = (containerClass *)data;
    //FINALLY, DO THE JOB WITH PROPERTY!!!
}
```

This works well and does the job. Anyway, I was wondering if there is a smarter and cleaner way to achieve the same aim, maybe without using pointers to static functions, or by defining some kind of pattern to be reused everytime I need to have the same mechanism.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to use use templates to improve the type safety of what you are doing:

```
template< class ParamType >
void childClass::setClickHandler_External(void (*extFun)(string, ParamType *),
                                          ParamType *data)
{
    // Set the external event handler
    clickHandler_External = (void ()(string,void*))extFun;
    clickHandler_External_Data = (void*)data;
}
```

Then you can simplify  the containerClass implementation as such:

```
// Container Class
class containerClass {
    childClass child;
    static void clickHandler(string property, containerClass *data);
}

containerClass::containerClass() {
    // Set the event handler
    child.setClickHandler_External(&containerClass::clickHandler, this);
}

void containerClass::clickHandler(string property, containerClass *data) {
    //FINALLY, DO THE JOB WITH PROPERTY!!!
}
```

While it's great that this cleans up the implementation, removing the explicit casting from all the container implementors, that's not really the point.  The point is to prevent you from passing wrong pointers into setClickHandler_External, causing crashes on the back end when events get dispatched.

My next step would take us further from your implementation, but would require more details about what you are actually doing.  Depending on your needs that would be looking into:

- Inheritance: should containerClass derive from childClass?  That would provide access to a virtual function table that we could override.
- Functors: look at boost::function and boost::bind to implement functors, eliminating the intermediate static function call.
- Lambda Functions: bleeding edge (C++11 or later), but may be a good fit for this kind of forwarding function.

Answer (score 2):

Gtkmm uses the sigc++ library to take care of all of this for you. There is no need to write it yourself.

Documentation links:

- [Signals overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-signals-overview.html.en)
- [Appendix with detailed information](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-signals.html.en)

So, in this case, I would use something like

```
button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(container, &containerClass::clickHandler));
```

while making sure that `containerClass::clickHander` has the appropriate number of arguments.